# How can I parse descriptive text to a DateTime object?

Tags: .net, parsing, open-source

Are there any existing libraries in existence that will parse a datetime from a plaintext phrase? I'm looking for something similar to Remember The Milk or Outlook, where the user can enter "next tuesday at 6pm" or "tonight at 7" and the library can spit out {4/28/2009 18:00:00} or {4/25/2009 19:00:00}. I'm considering writing my own, but I'd rather use/contribute to something already in existence.

Comment: Write your own if you can, there's no such thing as far as I know. Could be wrong though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datejs is an open-source JavaScript Date Library that does what you're asking for: http://www.datejs.com/

It's not .NET, but it is Open Source.